# Using an HTML Link

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a C# ASP.NET application that throws an `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object`" exception.

The line that throws the exception is

```
HtmlLink cssTemplate = new HtmlLink();
```

I am using the `cssTemplate` variable in my site to set the `CSS` sheet on my `masterpage` based on the logged in user.

Any ideas as to why I would get this error on instantiation of the cssTemplate object?

Update: The entire snippet from the exception is

```
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stack Trace: at LRMasterPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e in
LRMasterPage.master.cs:line 49
Target Site: Void Page_Load(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
```

I am wondering now if it is the System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal that might actually be the issue.

Comment: Are you sure this is the line you get the error from? It seems a bit odd..

Comment: I agree it seems odd. When I look at my code and match up the line number, this is the line.

Comment: Could you post more of the code so we can get some context?

Comment: Why match line numbers? You can't attach a debugger?

Comment: This is happening on my production server. When I run the code locally, I do not get the error.

Comment: Hm that makes it even weirder.. Still there are methods to debug remotely, or could you enable verbose errors for a little while? What does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: What happens in your Page_Load?

Comment: My first guess: The binaries on your production server do not match the code in your development environment...

Comment: Please make sure you have published properly to Production.